# Instance variable data return to default when overriding the function

Tags: actionscript-3, instance-variables

I've set the var of an instance in a function, but when I'm overriding the function, the var somehow got set back to default. If its static var then its ok. What's wrong here?

```
public function login($i:int):void
{
    Result.getInstance().coin = $i;
    // trace Result.getInstance().coin is 100 
}

override public function login($i:int):void
{
    super.login($i);
   // trace Result.getInstance().coin is 0 
}
```

Comment: in your override function what happens if you `trace ("$i is... " + $i);` is it expected 100? Referring to `super` might be the problem, why? Should it not be exactly like original login function's code?

Comment: if I trace $i in the override function, the value is correct. But somehow after  the super, the instance value is reset. Currently have to set 'Result.getInstance().coin = $i;' again after the super. If it's before super, it will become default value again after the super.

Comment: Are you expecting `super.login($i);` to speak to the top function?

Comment: It looks like you are (ab)using a singleton to get "global" variables.

Comment: What values do you get for the parameter on the call to the overridden function? And what value do you pass?